# Is it more efficient to use set with pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a `dictionary` which looks as below:

```
maps = {'0': '0', '1': '1', '6': '9', '8': '8', '9': '6'}
```

I have a `set` which looks as below:

```
pairs = {("0", "0"), ("1", "1"), ("6", "9"), ("8", "8"), ("9", "6")}
```

I understand that `dictionary` gives the ability to define `key-value` pairs but other than that `is it more efficient to use set with pairs as compared to creating a dictionary object?`

In what situation, should we use a `set with pairs`?

Comment: use it when `set()` will be more useful for you. When you don't need `key-value` - ie. pairs `(x, y)`

Comment: it depends on what are you going to do , so based on that you have to choose the best data structure that would  work for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in asking about efficiency, because a `map` and a `set` do entirely different things.   The immediate question is, what are you trying to do?

Do you need to see what digit goes with another digit?   I.e., do you have `"6"`, and want to look it up and get `"9"`?   If so, use a `map`.

Do you need to see if a particular pair exists?   I.e., do you have `("6":"9")` and want see if it exists?   Then use `set`.

In regards to efficiency, both are going to be efficient went asked to store what they are made for, and inefficient went coerced into some unintended use.